# placing a jpanel on top of a jpanel from another class

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel, paint

I am trying to make a Jpanel in one class appear on top of the Jpanel from another class. I can do this in a roundabout way but I know I will regret it in the long run. My frame class contains the main Jpanel with buttons and I want to temporarily place another Jpanel on top of it with buttons. I tried to simplify my code. Pay attention to the ShopButton Method and the Shop Class below the first chunk of code. That's what I am trying to focus on. I am trying to place the Shop JPanel over the existing "frame" (this is what I called my class) JPanel.

```
package sonomaroller;
//Bunch of imports i didnt include
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;

public class frame extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    //buttons
    private JButton Button4;
    //images
    private Image Sonoma;
    private Image pic;
    //booleans
    private boolean loaded;
    public boolean inTown = true;
    public boolean isShopping = false;
    //variables
    //strings 
    //arrays
    public Integer[] attributes = {0,1,2}; //attk - 0, def - 1 , magic - 2
    //new jpanel
    JTextPane field = new JTextPane();
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(field);
    //calling another class making it public
    public Shop shopping = new Shop();

    public void run(){
    }

    public frame(){
        loadpics();
        attackButton();
        magicButton();
        travelButton();
        shopButton();
        textField(); 
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString(firstName +givenName+ secondName,225,40);
        g.drawRect(100, 50, 350, 275);
        if(loaded){
            g.drawImage(Sonoma,101,51,350,275,null);
        }
        if(isShopping==true){
           shopping.paint(g);
        }
    }

    public void shopButton(){
        //for shop button
        Button4= new JButton("Shop");
        Button4.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Event) {
                loaded=false; 
                isShopping=true;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        Button4.setBounds(130, 485, 90, 30);
        add(Button4);
    }

    public void loadpics(){
        Sonoma = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Camtronius\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SonomaRoller\\src\\sonomaroller\\Sonoma.png").getImage();
        System.out.println("i was called?");  
        loaded = true;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____Shop Class

```
public class Shop extends JPanel {
    public JButton CloseButton;
    public Shop(){
        CloseButton();
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        System.out.println("shop is working");
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(100, 50, 350, 275);
        g.drawRect(100, 50, 350, 275);
    } 
    public void CloseButton(){
        //for 
        CloseButton= new JButton("Exit Shop");
        CloseButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Event) {
                System.out.println("am i alive?");
            }
        });
        CloseButton.setBounds(100, 100, 90, 30);
        add(CloseButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`, then you can place the components normally and let swing take care of drawing them:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Sample {
    private static class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // Some background drawing
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    Sample() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button atop drawing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        JPanel panel = new ImagePanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 50, 50));

        JButton button = new JButton("Sample button");
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Sample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

... results in:

[image: Button atop oval]

Comment: Wow, I cant believe that worked... Thank you so much! I need to go review the difference between paint and paint componenet

Comment: actually now it only adds the button and doesnt draw the filled rectangle I want it to. I will try to figure out why. Thanks

Comment: @CameronRoberson `paint()` is the top level painting method and is responsible to calling `paintComponent()`, `paintChildren()` and `paintBorder()`. So usually you only want to override `paintComponent()`. If something does not get drawn below your child components, my wild guess is that either they do not respect the opaqueness contract, or paint over the background. For buttons you can do a quick check if it's painting over by setting `button.setContentAreaFilled(false); button.setOpaque(false);` and see if the background shows through.